# Mapbox console errors since Xcode 9 upgrade

Tags: ios, mapbox

Ever since upgrading to Xcode 9 (and thus Swift 4), my Mapbox framework is causing new errors to show in the console, despite working perfectly in simulators and on devices. I don't know if these errors are just now being displayed in the console since the upgrade or if there is a conflict with the upgrade. What do these errors mean and how can they be resolved?

```
2017-09-19 17:08:30.581029-0700 Sconewolf[424:41561] Task <A0F6DE13-B42F-4EF9-88F7-3152B15872CD>.<3> finished with error - code: -999
2017-09-19 17:08:30.581804-0700 Sconewolf[424:41305] Task <2F8EA368-3840-4882-AF01-9790EE5ACF14>.<1> HTTP load failed (error code: -999 [1:89])
2017-09-19 17:08:30.583470-0700 Sconewolf[424:41310] Task <2F8EA368-3840-4882-AF01-9790EE5ACF14>.<1> finished with error - code: -999
2017-09-19 17:08:30.584892-0700 Sconewolf[424:41305] Task <FCA978A6-9C44-4BF6-A817-7CD8565A9416>.<4> finished with error - code: -999
2017-09-19 17:08:30.585156-0700 Sconewolf[424:41305] Task <DCF01078-A70B-44B7-8D70-EF3603EB643A>.<5> finished with error - code: -999
2017-09-19 17:08:30.585398-0700 Sconewolf[424:41305] Task <37C791ED-8F97-4493-A34F-42621D33EE1F>.<2> finished with error - code: -999
2017-09-19 17:08:30.585440-0700 Sconewolf[424:41310] Task <37C791ED-8F97-4493-A34F-42621D33EE1F>.<2> HTTP load failed (error code: -999 [1:89])
2017-09-19 17:08:30.587078-0700 Sconewolf[424:41305] Task <0679FDC8-90C2-4B91-A623-7FBF1C859BEF>.<6> finished with error - code: -999
2017-09-19 17:08:30.587105-0700 Sconewolf[424:41561] Task <0679FDC8-90C2-4B91-A623-7FBF1C859BEF>.<6> HTTP load failed (error code: -999 [1:89])
```

Comment: I see the same logs when calling `cancel` on a `URLSessionTask`, my guess is that Mapbox is cancelling tasks/requests. I'm unsure how to disable these logs

Answer (score 1):

This is caused due to some bug in Apple libraries. Please read the below thread:
[Apple Developer Forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/88020)

There is nothing wrong with your code and won't cause any problem in the application.